# Why shouldn't I migrate my distributed .NET 4.0 application to .NET 4.5?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, upgrade, .net-4.5

I have read the list of breaking changes listed at [Application Compatibility in the .NET Framework 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887.aspx).  It seems like the biggest issue with migrating a .NET 4.0 application to .NET 4.5 would be that a .NET 4.5 application can't run on XP.  If I can be assured that this will never be necessary, what are the biggest concerns in migrating a distributed application from .NET 4.0 to .NET 4.5 ?  Are any of the listed issues more significant than they appear to be?

Comment: None of the listed issues are significant.  Until one of the them breaks your app, then it is suddenly **very** significant.  Nobody's crystal ball is going to give you the answer you need.  You'll need to test your app on 4.5 yourself.

Comment: @smartcaveman - Your question is not clear. The compatibility concerns Microsoft considers significant enough you already known. They are only significant if they effect your application. The fact .NET 4.5 does not support Windows XP is not problem.  Furthermore Microsoft explains the impact and any possible workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually risky to migrate a an app even when there are no known compatibility issues. In this case when there are known breaking changes I would avoid the migration.

A simple test won't reveal specific cases where the application could behave differently.

Comment: Thanks. I agree if that's the whole story.  But my app is in continuous development and I would like to try to keep the technologies I can use as current as possible.  I'm hoping for an answer that is a little more focused on this specific scenario.

Comment: @smartcaveman - Unless you have a need to migrate to .NET 4.5 you shouldn't migrate until said time you understand what the impact will be.